# How to find and update XML file content using python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

for example

```
 <managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/a" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="b">enabled</p>
          <p name="c">640ms</p>
          <p name="d">320ms</p>
          <p name="e">640ms</p>
          <p name="f">1280ms</p>
          <p name="g">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="new" distName="AL-76867/MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/b" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="h">320ms</p>
          <p name="i">enabled</p>
          <p name="j">640ms</p>
          <p name="k">320ms</p>
          <p name="l">640ms</p>
          <p name="a">1280ms</p>
          <p name="l">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/c" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="p">enabled</p>
          <p name="q">640ms</p>
          <p name="r">320ms</p>
          <p name="s">640ms</p>
          <p name="t">1280ms</p>
          <p name="u">6</p>
    </managedObject>
```

Here in this example first I want to update `(distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/[a or b or c]")` to `(distName="MB-85409/TB-85409/ST-4/[a or b or c]")`

after doing this to whole XML file .

after doing this I want to update the values of tag `name="a"` for which `<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85409/TB-85409/ST-4/[a or b or c] >`

How can I do this , I have an XML file of 40000+ lines.

EDIT1

```
with open("C:/files/abcd.xml", "w+") as file:
    xml_data = file.read()
    xml_data.replace("85409","85904")
    file.write("outPuta.xml")
```

EDIT2

```
soup = bs(content,"xml")
    loc = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/+SMOD+-+[1-9]')
    for i in soup.find_all('managedObject', distName=loc):
        locat=i.find('p',{'name':'moduleLocation'})
        locat.string="3444 South texas"
```

By this code I am trying to find `distname` which matched with `regex loc`, and inside `managedObject`, i trying finding tag `<p name="moduleLocation" 4444 New York>` and I want to update `"4444 New York"` to `"3444 South texas"` and this is giving me below mentioned error

```
locat.string="3444 South texas"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right, this will find all `distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/[a or b or c]"` tags and replace `85404` for `85409` and update `<p name="a">` tag:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


xml_data = ''' <managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/a" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="b">enabled</p>
          <p name="c">640ms</p>
          <p name="d">320ms</p>
          <p name="e">640ms</p>
          <p name="f">1280ms</p>
          <p name="g">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="new" distName="AL-76867/MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/b" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="h">320ms</p>
          <p name="i">enabled</p>
          <p name="j">640ms</p>
          <p name="k">320ms</p>
          <p name="l">640ms</p>
          <p name="a">1280ms</p>
          <p name="l">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/c" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="p">enabled</p>
          <p name="q">640ms</p>
          <p name="r">320ms</p>
          <p name="s">640ms</p>
          <p name="t">1280ms</p>
          <p name="u">6</p>
    </managedObject>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup('<data>' + xml_data + '</data>', 'xml')

r = re.compile(r'^MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/(?:a|b|c)')

for o in soup.find_all('managedObject', distName=r):
    o['distName'] = o['distName'].replace('85404', '85409')
    p = o.find('p', {'name':'a'})
    p.string = 'UPDATED ' + p.string

soup.data.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85409/TB-85409/ST-4/a" operation="open" version="xL20A_1911_002">
<p name="a">UPDATED 320ms</p>
<p name="b">enabled</p>
<p name="c">640ms</p>
<p name="d">320ms</p>
<p name="e">640ms</p>
<p name="f">1280ms</p>
<p name="g">6</p>
</managedObject>
<managedObject class="new" distName="AL-76867/MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/b" operation="open" version="xL20A_1911_002">
<p name="h">320ms</p>
<p name="i">enabled</p>
<p name="j">640ms</p>
<p name="k">320ms</p>
<p name="l">640ms</p>
<p name="a">1280ms</p>
<p name="l">6</p>
</managedObject>
<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85409/TB-85409/ST-4/c" operation="open" version="xL20A_1911_002">
<p name="a">UPDATED 320ms</p>
<p name="p">enabled</p>
<p name="q">640ms</p>
<p name="r">320ms</p>
<p name="s">640ms</p>
<p name="t">1280ms</p>
<p name="u">6</p>
</managedObject>
```

---

EDIT: To change `85404` to `85409` in every `distName=`, you can do this:

```
for o in soup.find_all('managedObject', {'distName': True}):
    o['distName'] = o['distName'].replace('85404', '85409')
```

---

EDIT2: To replace the whole file:

```
with open("C:/files/abcd.xml", "r") as f_in:
    xml_data = f_in.read()

with open("C:/files/output.xml", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(xml_data.replace("85409","85904"))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej I will try it , I just have a little doubt that when you updated the p tag <p name="a"> will it be updated for whole XML file whenever < name="a"> comes or it will update <p name="a > tag when managedObject matched **<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85409/TB-85409/ST-4/[a or b or c] >**, I want to update p tag whenever ST-4 in managedObject otherwise I have to pass unchanged.

Comment: @AkashRathor It will update `<p name="a">` only inside `<managedObject>` with `distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/[a or b or c]"`

Comment: And If I want to update "85404" to "85409" on whole XML file , regardless on its position, how can I do that .?Sorry I am asking too many questions , I am new to this .

Comment: That's ok we can change that in distName, but I want to know can we change it in whole sheet just like we do in notepad find and replace all type of thing ?

Comment: @AkashRathor Then you can use `str.replace`, for example read the XML to variable `xml_data`, then do `xml_data = xml_data.replace('85404', '85409')` and save `xml_data` to new file.

Comment: I tried to do the same but it it deleted the whole content of the file and just wrote output.xml insite the file , See EDIT1 , and suggest what to do here. Thank you @AndrejKesely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219706/discussion-between-akash-rathor-and-andrej-kesely).

Comment: while I used your first answer I am getting error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string',See EDIT2